# Executing an Environment Variable based path in the Powershell Terminal

Tags: powershell

I want to execute a path in the Windows Powershell terminal based on the concatenation of an environment variable and a string, in **one line**.

For instance, `cmd.exe` allows me to execute the following:

```
c:\temp> %PYTHON2PATH%\python.exe main.py
```

With Powershell, it seems that one needs to refer to the environment variable using:

```
PS c:\temp> $Env:PYTHON2PATH\python.exe
```

Although this only works if I press **TAB** (which then de-references the variable), before pressing Enter. Is there is way do this without having to de-reference it using the TAB key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the call operator (`&`) if you want to invoke command strings with unexpanded variables:

```
& $env:PYTHON2PATH\python.exe
```

or

```
& "${env:PYTHON2PATH}\python.exe"
```